# Image loading using keras preprocessing

Tags: keras

I have a question about `load_img` by `keras`. It may be too simple for you. Keras provides `from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img`, which loads an image into `PIL` format. I was wondering if it is actually implementing the pillow method: `from PIL import Image` and then `Image.open()`, or cv2.imread() (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/examples/class_activation_maps.py#L36; https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-following-python-packages-CV2-PIL-and-OPENCV-When-can-I-use-each-of-them)

Answer (score 0):

The definition is given here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py#L79